# Why does Angular require a server in their tutorials?

Tags: angular

Looking at the [quick start](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) and [step by step](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html) tutorials, Angular requires a server.

**Why does Angular require a server?**

I'd like to focus on UI and having a working server all the time slows me down - especially in a big project, where the server is not stable all the time and has tons of integrations which aren't configured locally.

Edit [2015/08/12]: It seems that the server is required. Trying to run the [step by step guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html), doesn't work when loading the html statically (without a server). Nothing is shown. The `myapp` tag just doesn't get bounded the controller.

Comment: Running Angular doesn't require a server - you can run it off of a local js file

Comment: how would you get the app into your browser otherwise?

Comment: then how you going to use `routes` in angularjs?

Comment: If you are using webstorm all you have to do is right click the main html file and select run. This sets up the IDE local server. Angular 2.0 samples here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples

Answer (score 6):

Angular doesn't require a server per se, it is a static JS library.

However, you may quickly run into problems as soon as you start performing AJAX requests (e.g. when writing directives using `templateUrl`, loading partials using `ngInclude`, etc.). AJAX requests to local files are not allowed by most browsers as a security measure (although this feature can sometimes be disabled, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)).

Bottom line, Angular suggests using a static server as a best practice, because it ensures that all features in their tutorials will work as described. For the most basic development, I use [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) which is very quick to fire up.

Answer (score 6):

For security purpose, browser does not allow direct request on file system. It gives you error while working with routing and ajax requests in angular. So, you have to use simple HTTP server or you can create it using `nodejs`.

Refer [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

**Install apache2 server in linux :**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After that you just have to put your code in `/var/www/yourDirectory`. Now you can access your code via `http://localhost/yourDirectory`

Comment: The browser has no problem working with local files. It loads local HTMLs , in addition to CSS and JS. If I don't want to use routing or network requests, why would I need a server for learning Angular? Isn't it supposed to be a client side framework?

Comment: Server is needed for routing the states.

Comment: Why do you think "Server is needed for routing the states."?