# Running quick-start plunker on chrome browser?

Tags: angular, plunker

I am trying to run angular2 quickstart example of plunker in my local environment.

For this, I followed these steps-

1. Download all files from https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html into local folder on my machine.
2. Double-click on index.html to run application.

this way, I am able to run application on Firefox. but I get an error on chrome-

> zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:101 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Adi/angular2-RC5-plunker/app/main.ts. Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

How do I run this quick-start application on chrome browser successfully?

[chrome error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCt1s.png)

Comment: The quick start has a node lite server built into it. I would recommend using this instead. https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: **Unbelievable** that there's no way to to run a project when you have the complete source code. What's missing? Is the configuration missing? Are the dependencies missing??? In Java, for example, there's a single file, pom or gradle, that provides you with all the configuration/dependencies needed to run a project. What's missing in Angular 2???

Comment: Also, strange that this runs on Firefox but not on Chrome. I thought Angular requires some server side functionality for part of it's core components. Though I would be really glad it wasn't the case. See [Why does Angular require a server in their tutorials?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31624686/435605).

Answer (score 1):

Combining steps to fix with the process explanation. Follow the numbered fixes to fix the configuration.

* Solution based on `npm` as used in the [official Angular 2 guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html).

[Angular 2 plunker link](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/eplnkr.html) redirected me to an Angular 2 QuickStart example (which is different from Plunker's Angular 2 template - FYI).

I downloaded Plunker's project, as Adi99 did.

I then tried following the steps in Angular's [QuickStart setup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) but failed on `npm install`.

Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/alik/Dev/help2/package.json'`.

**Fix step 1**: Download `package.json` from [Angular 2 QuickStart source code](https://github.com/kilaka/quickstart/blob/master/package.json), put it in the root's project folder and change in the file `src` with `.`.

Running `npm install` now passes successfully, probably downloading all the necessary dependencies.

The next step in the QuickStart tutorial is to run `npm start` which fails on `error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: './'`.

**Fix step 2**: Download `tsconfig.json` from [Angular 2 QuickStart source code](https://github.com/kilaka/quickstart/blob/master/src/tsconfig.json) and put it in the root's project folder..

Running `npm start` now passes successfully, creating the server and opening a browser page with the address `http://localhost:3000/`, rendering Angular 2 code successfully with the message:

> Hello Angular

Hope this helped and **Angular team :)** will make the initial configuration easier. It's a bad architecture to have lots of configuration files. Hard to understand what's needed, why and how to change it.
For example, in [Angular's QuickStart source project](https://github.com/kilaka/quickstart), there are 10 configuration files: `bs-config.e2e.json`, `bs-config.json`, `karma-test-shim.js`, `karma.conf.js`, `package.json`, `protractor.config.js`, `tslint.json`, `src/systemjs.config.extras.js`, `src/systemjs.config.js`, `src/tsconfig.json`